# How can I set an enum with an if-statement or a for-loop?

Tags: java, android-studio, for-loop, if-statement, enums

I want that people can assess themselves. For that they need to enter a number between 0 and 10 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). Depending on their number my enum should switch.

My enum is called "knowlede" and I got four different steps of "knowledge".
0-3 = Beginner // 4-6 = Advanced // 7-9 = Professional // 10 = Master

My idea was to set the users enum level with an if statement and/or a for loop.
This is my code so far, but as you can see I could shorten this code but I don't know how; I read some other threads but for some reason they didn't work or I didnt't get them.

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public Wissenstand Bestätigung(View v) {
    TextView uWissen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wissen_Titel);
    TextView pWarung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wissen);
    TextView eWissen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_eingabeWissentsstand);
            if ("0".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Beginner;
            } else if ("1".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Beginner;
            } else if ("2".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Beginner;
            } else if ("3".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Beginner;
            } else if ("4".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener;
            } else if ("5".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener;
            } else if ("6".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener;
            } else if ("7".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Pro;
            } else if ("8".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Pro;
            } else if ("9".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.Pro;
            } else if ("10".equals(eWissen.getText().toString())) {
                knowledge = Wissenstand.GrandMaster;
            } else {
                uWissen.setText("Fehler gefunden!");
                uWissen.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
                pWarung.setText("Gib eine Zahl von 0 bis 10 ein!\n0,5-er Schritte sind nicht erlaubt!\nWeitere Informationen kannst du der Legende entnehmen!");
                pWarung.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
            }
    return null;
}
```

If you need some help because u don't understand some words, text me, I'll answer as fast as I can.
The language is "german".

Comment: You could also parse the `String` to an `int` and check based on that. E.g. `if (in < 4){k = Beginner}else if(in < 7){k = Intermediate} else { k = Master}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd implement that something like this:

```
enum KnowledgeLevel
{
    BEGINNER, ADVANCED, PROFESSIONAL, MASTER;

    static KnowledgeLevel fromUserInput(final int input)
    {
        if (input >= 10) {
            return MASTER;
        }
        else if (input >= 7) {
            return PROFESSIONAL;
        }
        else if (input >= 4) {
            return ADVANCED;
        }
        else {
            return BEGINNER;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage would be:

```
final String input = "5";
KnowledgeLevel level = KnowledgeLevel.fromUserInput( Integer.parseInt(input) );
```

This has a few advantages over your implementation:

1. There's less repetition because I used ranges `>=` rather than explicitly mentioning all integers
2. It separates the concerns of receiving a user input and converting that to a knowledge level.
3. It places the mapping of integers to levels in a place where its easily reusable.

Comment: Now there is an error "fromUserInput is never used". So is this the method my checking-button should have?
I want that a button next to my editText checks the input on editText and then set the knowladge depending on the number inside the editText.
Additionally I can't use "findViewById" and that causes i can use "setText" on my textViews.

Comment: Not using a method is not an error. It's just a warning. But yes, use `KnowledgeLevel.fromUserInput` when they press the button.

Comment: unfortunatly I'm not sure how to do that in my code. I made a new methode called "fromUsersInput" and the check-button got the onClickMethod "fromUsersInput" but in the code you gave me its still "never used". And i dont know exactly how to give the literal from my editText to your method, because only then my enum will set, right?

Comment: I can't help you without seeing it. Feel free to post a new question with the updated code.

Comment: Here's a new/updated code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484272/how-can-i-set-my-enum-with-the-value-the-user-enter-in-a-edittext

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` which stores the mapping of ratings to enum values:

```
Map<String, Wissenstand> ratingToWissenstand = new HashMap<>();

ratingToWissenstand.put("0", Wissenstand.Beginner);
ratingToWissenstand.put("1", Wissenstand.Beginner);
ratingToWissenstand.put("2", Wissenstand.Beginner);
ratingToWissenstand.put("3", Wissenstand.Beginner);
ratingToWissenstand.put("4", Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener);
ratingToWissenstand.put("5", Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener);
ratingToWissenstand.put("6", Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener);
ratingToWissenstand.put("7", Wissenstand.Pro);
ratingToWissenstand.put("8", Wissenstand.Pro);
ratingToWissenstand.put("9", Wissenstand.Pro);
ratingToWissenstand.put("10", Wissenstand.GrandMaster);

knowledge = ratingToWissenstand.get(eWissen.getText().toString());
if (knowledge == null) {
    // Handle invalid eWissen-text value
}
```

The map can be made a static field and initialised only once. Then you only have the `get`-Call in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(eWissen.getText().toString());
if(value < 4){
    knowledge = Wissenstand.Beginner;
}else if(value < 7){
    knowledge = Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener;
}else if(value < 10){
    knowledge = Wissenstand.Pro;
}else{
    knowledge = Wissenstand.GrandMaster;
}
```

Comment: FYI, `Integer.valueOf` returns a boxed `Integer` which you immediately unbox again. A very small optimisation would be to use `parseInt`

Comment: @Michael Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this as pseudo code below.
You define an array with all possible answers for **knowledge**.
Then, you validate option is a number in proper range 1-10.
Finally if selected option is in proiper range, you assign **knowledge** from array or else condition.

```
Wissenstand knowledges[] ={ Wissenstand.Beginner,Wissenstand.Beginner,Wissenstand.Beginner,Wissenstand.Beginner,Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener,Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener,Wissenstand.Fortgeschrittener,Wissenstand.Pro,Wissenstand.Pro,Wissenstand.GrandMaster};

int option = -1;
try{
    option=Integer.getInt(eWissen.getText().toString()); 
}
catch(Exception e){
}
if (option>0 && option <=knowledge.size()){
    knowledge=knowledges[option];
}
else{
    uWissen.setText("Fehler gefunden!");
    uWissen.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
                pWarung.setText("Gib eine Zahl von 0 bis 10 ein!\n0,5-er Schritte sind nicht erlaubt!\nWeitere Informationen kannst du der Legende entnehmen!");
    pWarung.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}
```