# How can I set my enum with the value the user enter in a EditText?

Tags: android, if-statement, enums, android-edittext

I have a editText where the users enter a number between 0 and 10. Depending on their entered number the enum (knowledge) will set.
Here's my code so far:

```
public int fromUserInput() {
    TextView eWissen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_eingabeWissentsstand);
    eWissen.getText().toString() == Zahl;
    return Zahl;
}

private enum Wissenstand
{
    BEGINNER, FORTGESCHRITTENER, PRO, GRANDMASTER;

    static Wissenstand fromUserInput(final int input)
    {
        if (input >= 10) {
            return GRANDMASTER;
        } else if (input >= 7) {
            return PRO;
        } else if (input >= 4) {
            return FORTGESCHRITTENER;
        } else if (input >= 0) {
            return BEGINNER;
        } else {
            TextView uWissen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wissen_Titel);
            TextView pWarung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wissen);


        uWissen.setText("Fehler gefunden!");
        uWissen.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
        pWarung.setText("Gib eine Zahl von 0 bis 10 ein!\n0,5-er Schritte sind nicht erlaubt!\nWeitere Informationen kannst du der Legende entnehmen!");
        pWarung.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Additionally I can't use "findViewById" in my "static Wissenstand from UserInput(Final int input) {...}" method for some reason.
If you need something tell me, I help wherever I can.

Comment: Take care of the Java naming convention. properties should start with lower case character

Comment: The reason you cant call `findViewById` is because it's a [method from the view class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) (And also [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))). Your enum isn't (and shouldn't) be a View

Answer (score 0):

The `else` condition shouldn't be in that class.

You want something like:

```
public Wissenstand Bestätigung(View v) {
    TextView uWissen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wissen_Titel);
    TextView pWarung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Wissen);
    TextView eWissen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_eingabeWissentsstand);

    knowledge = Wissenstand.fromUserInput( Integer.parseInt( eWissen.getText().toString() );

    if(knowledge == null){
         uWissen.setText("Fehler gefunden!");
         uWissen.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
         pWarung.setText("Gib eine Zahl von 0 bis 10 ein!\n0,5-er Schritte sind nicht erlaubt!\nWeitere Informationen kannst du der Legende entnehmen!");
         pWarung.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, it's really hard to answer questions with code that's not using English names for things. Your English is clearly good - I would convert everything to English before posting here in future.

Comment: I also tend to use English names but sometimes it's more appropriate to use another language. But at least, it would be good to avoid local characters like the german "Umlaute". "Bestaetignug" would be just one letter longer and help to avoid potential problems.

Comment: @Pelocho Perhaps, but if that's the way he likes to do it, who are we to tell him not to?

Comment: Well, of course code in the language you want. English isn't either my mother tongue but I code in English. It's easier to share your code with any colleague (and you never know when that can happen)

Comment: @Michael yes, i wanted to change it if i finished this part of my app. Thanks for the compliment (good english) Ithought its "too" bad so people couldnt answer caused by my bad english. Well thanks ^^. I'll change it today or tomorrow.
(I know comments arent there for saying "thanks" but this time I just need to do it)

Comment: Android Studio want me to set a "Return" statement after the if statement. is "return null;" correct?

Comment: `return knowledge` or change the function definition to `public void Bestätigung(...`

Comment: Ok, I did it. My hopfully last question is: Is my enum now for the whole project set? For each layout? UNTIL I change it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `knowledge` must be a field of whatever class contains the `Bestätigung` method, so the value of `knowledge` for that instance of that class will stay the same unless you change it.

Comment: ok, got it!
"private Wissenstand knowledge;" says "Field cannot be converted into a local variable". What does this mean?How can i solve this?

Comment: I just realized my java "class" (correct: enum") isnt important anymore i guess. Everything in it wasnt used but my code in MainActivity had no errors so I guess my enum isnt nessecary.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` is not a "magical method" that looks for your views. It's actually a method of [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) or [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))

Inside your enum class you shouldn't use that kind of stuff. Just check the int value and if it's out of range throw an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
static Wissenstand fromUserInput(final int input)
    {
        if (input >= 10) {
            return GRANDMASTER;
        } else if (input >= 7) {
            return PRO;
        } else if (input >= 4) {
            return FORTGESCHRITTENER;
        } else if (input >= 0) {
            return BEGINNER;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value");    
        }
    }
```

When calling `fromUserInput` you should add the corresponding try-catch